# How do I make the parents processes wait for the children to finish using waitpid?

Tags: c, process, waitpid

I want to make the parent processes (P1 and P2) wait for their respective child processes(P3 and P4) to terminate using waitpid (**basically, parent processes can only terminate after the children terminates**). Here's the code below. I'm portuguese, sorry for having non-english words on the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
  int estado1, estado2;

  pid_t p = fork();
  pid_t k = fork();

  if(p>0) //Execução do pai
  {
    waitpid(p, &estado1, 0); //Don't know how waitpid works that well either
    waitpid(k, &estado2, 0);

    printf("p=%d: PID = %d;\t", p, getpid());
    // \t é para dar um tab (o que se usa nas indentações)

    sleep(45);

    printf("O processo pai terminou.\n");

    exit(0);
  }
  else if(p==0) //Execução do filho
  {
    printf("p=%d: PID = %d;\t", p, getpid());
    // \t é para dar um tab (o que se usa nas indentações)

    printf("O processo filho terminou.\n");

    exit(0);
  }
  else if(p<0)
  {
    printf("ERRO! p=%d\n", p);

    exit(p);
  }
}
```

This is what I have but I think it isn't right.
Thanks in advance.
Edit: Thanks to zeroSpook for fixing my text :)

Comment: Be aware that you will have 4 processes here, not three, because `pid_t k = fork();` happens in two processes.

Comment: Don't call a second fork before checking the result of the first one. And make sure to call the second fork onyly once.

Comment: Christian Gibbons, yes, I know that there will be 4 processes. The first one will be the father of the 2nd and 3rd one and the 2nd process will be the father of the 4th process right?

Comment: You never check if k > 0.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question a while ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466564/how-to-make-parent-process-wait-for-child-processes-to-finish/. Could be both this and that are caused by the same assignment?

Comment: @JörgFaschingbauer Yes, that's the same assignment, didn't think someone had already asked it here lol

Comment: So this is how assignments are performed by nowadays students :-)

Comment: @JörgFaschingbauer Ahah, it might be. I'm asking for help to understand the assignment, not to have it done by someone else. Even if someone wrote one right code here I wouldn't just copy/paste it, I would read it, understand it and do it my way xd